# How number can be used of a command while creating xml file

Tags: xml

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nf:rpc xmlns="http://www.cisco.com/nxos:1.0:cdpd"
        xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="110">
   <nf:get>
      <nf:filter type="subtree">
          <show>
              <vlan>
                  <id><1/></id>
              </vlan>
          </show>
     </nf:filter>
  </nf:get>
</nf:rpc>]]>]]>
```

content which I am passing on networking device named switch so that through this xml content, it could extract the command as mentioned in its tags like here command would be "show vlan id 1".

But when I run this file, it shows error as "

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<nf:rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">

  <nf:rpc-error>

    <nf:error-type>application</nf:error-type>

    <nf:error-tag>invalid-value</nf:error-tag>

    <nf:error-severity>error</nf:error-severity>

    <nf:error-message>Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name

f:base:1.0" message-id="110"&gt;&lt;nf:get&gt;&lt;nf:filter type="subtree"&gt;&lt;show&gt;&lt;vlan&gt;&lt;id&gt;&lt;

                                                                               ^

</show>

</nf:data>

</nf:rpc-reply>
```

"

Anybody please tell how to define a number in xml tag or any work around for this

Comment: Ya, that I know. I am asking about any workaround as how it can be written in  this xml thing so that could be run on switch??. Just for command - show queuing interface ethernet 1/1. we need to use <interface>1/1</interface> inside <ethernet> tag in order to make it run on switch. But what should be done for this thing???. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
<1/>
```

XML element/attribute names cannot begin with number, that is the reason for the error, it clearly says invalid element name. Correct the same and try.